# Loading JS click handler after AJAX call without .live()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hoo boy, I'm embarrassed to be back here again so soon, but I'm trying hard to learn more than just tons of HTML/CSS tricks. I'm more of a designer than a developer, but I'm trying to change that as best I can - so thanks in advance for all the help!

Long story short: I'm using AJAX to avoid page reloads. I use a click event to load content from an external .php file into a div named #content. This works great when I use a link outside of #content, aka in the navigation bar, which is static and does not change. It does NOT work when I try to make a link in #content, where the contents are generated from a set of external .php files containing HTML.

E.g., I use the navigation to go to "Foo". Within "Foo", there's a link to "Bar". If I click "Bar", it should replace the div containing "Foo" with "Bar", but instead does nothing. However, if I go to "Bar" using the navigation, it works fine.

(Does that make sense?)

I've found (with help) that this is because the AJAX has already done its job, so I need to set up a click handler to work AFTER things have loaded. All the sources I've tried to poke through on here have suggested .live(), but that is deprecated. The solution appears to be .on(), but I already use that for my main handler. I tried to make another with a different name and it didn't accomplish anything, so I'm stuck.

I'm wondering what I can do to my script to make it work, or suggestions on how to mess with it. Here's what I've got (feel free to crucify it) :

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    
    /* AJAX request handling, JS click event handler, animations */
    
    // Request content for placement
    function requestContent(url,id) {
            var http;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
               try { http = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
               catch(e) {}
               } 
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
               try { http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
               catch(e) {
                  try { http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } 
                  catch(e) {}
                  }
               }
            if(! http) {
               alert('\n\nSorry, unable to open a connection to the server.');
               return false;
               }
            http.onreadystatechange = function() { publishContent(http,id); };
            http.open('GET',url,true);
            http.send('');
        }

    // Dump content from RequestContent into #content DIV
    function publishContent(content,id) {
            try {
               if (content.readyState === 4) {
                  if(content.status === 200) {   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=content.responseText; }
                  else { alert('\n\nContent request error, status code:\n'+content.status+' '+content.statusText); }
                  }
               }
            catch(error) { alert('Error: '+error.name+' -- '+error.message); }
            }
    
    // Navigation click events
    $('.naviLink').on('click', function(e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.hash = this.hash; // Remove hash at end of URLs
        $('#content').hide(); // Prepare for new content, still testing this
        var content = $(e.currentTarget).data('request-content'); // Bind request to click
        requestContent('' + content , 'content');
        // Fade in animations, still testing
        $('#content').toggle(function() {
            $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
        });             
    });

   // Generated content click events
   $('.innerLink').on('click', function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = this.hash; // Remove hash at end of URLs
    $('#content').hide(); // Prepare for new content
    var content = $(e.currentTarget).data('request-content'); // Bind request to click
    requestContent('' + content , 'content');
    // Fade in animations
    $('#content').toggle(function() {
        $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
        });             
    });
    
});
```

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but here's an example of how I use the event to link things. This HTML would be inside the #content div, loaded from an outside source.

```html
<h1>Example From Within Externally Generated Content</h1>

        <p>"Foo bar foo bar foo foo foo bar."</p>

        <h1>Foo</h1>
        <p><b>
            <a href="#" class="innerLink" data-request-content="foo">Check out</a> Foo!</b>
        </p>

        <h1>Bar</h1>
        <p><b>
            <a href="#" class="innerLink" data-request-content="bar">See</a> some Bar!</b>
        </p>
```

I hope this is straightforward. Thank you!

Comment: The answer is right in the jQuery `on` documentation. "An event-delegation approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody): `$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {`". So what you are looking for is called event delegation and `on` is capable of doing this. The docs about `live` also point you in this direction with clear code examples ("As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on(...").

Comment: You can attach multiple event handlers to the same element with multiple instances of `.on()`, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: Also, your code will be simpler if you use [`jquery.ajax()` or one of the related convenience methods](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/)

Comment: All of this really confuses me... I'm still very new to this. But thank you... I'll keep trying to figure it out. :(